# Recursion in Javascript ES6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call the same method within a method in a Javascript ES6 class but it is not working.

```
class Client {
    constructor(connection) {
        this.channels = [];
        this.nickname = null;
        this.user = null;
        this.realName = null;
        connection.on('data', this.parse_message);
    }
    parse_message(message) {
        let messageObject = {};
        if (message.includes('\r\n')) {
            message = message.split('\r\n');
            message.forEach((el) => {
                this.parse_message(el); 
            });
        }
        else {
            message = message.split(' ');
            console.log('Message Received: ', JSON.stringify(message));
        }
    }
}
```

When ran I get this error `TypeError: this.parse_message is not a function`. I tried assigning `this` to a variable `self` at the top but that still didn't work.

Comment: Please show how you call this function / create a new object from the class. And what is connection?

Comment: @Sébastien I'm sorry if I'm not understanding correctly but the parse_message method is being called in the constructor at `     connection.on('data', this.parse_message);`  The Client class is being created in a separate class if you think I should post that?

Comment: No need I think @doodlemeister has the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an arrow function as the bound handler so that you can keep `this` associated with the method.

```
    connection.on('data', (...args) => this.parse_message(...args));
```

Now your `this` in the `forEach` callback will be the expected value.

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind explaining the (...args) part to me that would be awesome. I'm  a bit of an ES6 noob.

Comment: @IsiahL: Sure, in the function parameter position, it's just a way of collecting all the arguments from that point forward. So it's called a "rest" parameter, because it gives you an array of the rest of the arguments passed. At the call site, it does the opposite; it *passes* the Array of arguments to the function being called, but passes them as individual args instead of a collection. It's called "spread" syntax because it "spreads out" the content of the Array into the function being called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind in the constructor:

```
this.parse_message = this.parse_message.bind(this);
```

Bind-ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind